# creating a multiple image uploader like facebook in asp.net project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, cross-browser, image-uploading

I have tried to create a multiple image uploader like facebook in my asp.net project.
It is working good in Firefox8, Chrome(15.0.874.121 m),
but the multiple uploader is not working in IE8 and Safari3.2.3.
Then I have tried it by using javascript custom dialog. 
Now the problem is the dialog is working in IE only. Can't resolve this.

Qtn:
I have used file upload control like this
    `asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" multiple="multiple" accept="image/gif,image/png">`   
But it is selecting only single file in IE 8 and Safari 3.2.3 whereas in Firefox 8 and in Chrome it is working properly.
Is there any other property to make it possible to select multiple file in all the browsers?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error message? If so, please post it? What does you code look like? etc. etc. In other words, with this question, we cannot help you.

Comment: Hey sunny, were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally jquery pjugins work in all browsers so maybe it will be a good idea to use this technology. You can easily add javascript/jquery code to your asp.net page.

Have look at this one http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for link to uploadify.I have seen that following the stackoverflow discussions and major issue with this i am facing is uploadify provides multiple progressbar for multiple files.I need single progressbar like facebook for multiple file upload.